# Oracle SQL force a column to be null if (not) meeting a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I have a table `status`:

[image]

and I want the `completionDate` field of every record to be null if the `status.status` field's value is not `completed`

```
alter table status
        add constraint ck_completion
                check ( 
                        -- status.completiondate's value should be null
                    -- if (Lower(status.status) != 'complete')
                );
```

Because if the status is not complete or incomplete, there shouldn't be a completion date. How can I do it?

Comment: @GurV can we do something like a `DEFAULT` constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a table level constraint which allows only null values if status is not complete and any value when status is complete.

```
alter table status add constraint ck_completion check (
    lower(status) = 'complete'
    or completiondate is null
    )
```

If you don't want to accept nulls in completion date if the status is complete then try this:

```
alter table status add constraint ck_completion check (
    (
        lower(status) <> 'complete'
        and completiondate is null
        )
    or (
        lower(status) = 'complete'
        and completiondate is not null
        )
    )
```